# Typeerror: str() takes at most 3 arguments (8 given)

Tags: python

I am trying to create a function that shows a given course code is correct or not.
the course code starts with four letters and three numbers with space in-between them.

```
def checkCourseCode(input_word):
 course_name =str("COMP", "LASC", "ENGN")
 course_code =int(1,2,3,4,6)
 for CourseCode in input_word (course_name,'',course_code):
      if CourseCode == "COMP 123":
           print("True")
      else:
           print("False")  
input_word = input("Please select menu choice: ")
checkCourseCode(input_word)
```

If I take off the remaining 5 values from course_name I am still getting this error.

```
          Please select menu choice: COMP 123
          Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "e:\CourseCode.py", line 11, in <module>
           checkCourseCode(input_word)
           File "e:\UCourseCode.py", line 3, in checkCourseCode
           course_name =str("COMP", "LASC", "ENGN")
           TypeError: decoding str is not supported
```

Comment: What is `str("COMP", "LASC", "ENGN")` supposed to be doing?

Comment: Also, how does the second snippet relate to the first?

Comment: `str(object)` converts an object to a string.  `str(bytearray, encoding, errors)` converts a byte array into a strings.  It is not at all clear what you're doing, but it appears you're confusing `str()` with some other function.

Comment: Where is the line with the error in your code?

Comment: Please update your question with your *real* code which relates to the error traceback.

Comment: Your error traceback refers to checkCourseCode. What is that?

Comment: Your error traceback refers to course_name=str(....  Where is that in your function?

Comment: Just updated the real code.

Comment: I see you have edited your post again, but I beg to differ. You still haven’t posted your real code.

Comment: The real code doesn't include the one line of code that your stack trace complains about

Comment: it is the real code.

Comment: Ok, finally. But did you mean: course_name = [“COMP", "LASC", "ENGN"]. ?

Comment: Ok so going back to the first comment - "What is `str("COMP", "LASC", "ENGN") `supposed to be doing? "

Comment: and to preempt the next question, what is `int(1,2,3,4,6)` supposed to be doing?

Comment: if I don't use str I am getting this error.                                                                
Please select menu choice: COMP 123
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\Uni Course\Comp636\python\CourseCode.py", line 11, in <module>
    checkCourseCode(input_word)
  File "e:\Uni Course\Comp636\python\CourseCode.py", line 5, in checkCourseCode
    for CourseCode in input_word (course_name,'',course_code):
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Ok,you’re making progress now. I suggest you take your current code and ask a new question, along with that error traceback.

Comment: Please post a completely new question.

Comment: I can't ask one more question as the forum is not allowing me. Thanks for your help tho.

Comment: How much longer do you have to wait? I thought you could post a new question every 40 minutes.

Comment: 1day left. any suggestions? Thank you

Comment: Ok, I had no idea it was that long. You need to gain 125 rep to post more frequently:-(

Comment: I think I understand where your going, but what is the course code check for? Are you trying to check if it is a valid code or if it is an integer?

Comment: I just want to check the given code is valid or not.

Comment: Valid in the sense that the code is in the course database (in this case the `course_code` variable), right?

Comment: Yes! the course is in this course_code variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In python, lists and tuples do not require types (they are dynamic). `str` and `int` are constructors.

```py
course_names = ("COMP", "LASC", "ENGN")
course_codes = ("215", "123", "1705")
```

You could set course_codes as an int, but for my example I used strings as it'll be less problematic, and also lets you use special characters too.

---

However lists are not the best way to do this. For example, course `COMP` may have course code `215` but course `LASC` may not. To insure this problem doesn't occur, use dictionaries. (Dictionaries don't have to be typed too.)

```py
courses = {
  "COMP":("215", "123"),
  "LASC":("215", "1712"),
  "ENGN":("281", "192")
}
```

The example above lets you access a key (or a course in our case), and get the value (the class codes for each course). Note that dictionaries are mutable (can be changed) while tuples are not.

---

Your original function is broken (did you forget a comma in the for loop?). While I see what you were trying to do, it isn't the best way as you have to loop through each item, which makes it go slower. Plus it also has the same issue that I noted with using lists.

This function is much more organized and neat. Let's go through it step by step.

```py
def checkCourseCode(input_word):
    input_data = input_word.split(" ")
```

Here we are using a method of the str object, split, which lets us seperate a string by a character. So if our input was "COMP 123", the split method turns it into ["COMP", "123"].

```py
    if len(input_data) != 2:
        return False
```

We only want 2 things, the course name and course code. If the user inputs something extra, it might cause an issue. Here we are making sure that it is exactly 2 items and if not, it is not a valid course.

```py
    if input_data[0] in courses:
```

This line checks if the course name is in our database (courses dict).

```py
        if input_data[1] in courses[input_data[0]]:
          print("True")
          return True
```

We are doing the same thing we did last time. Only this time we are getting the value from the key (getting the codes from the course) and checking if the code the user inputted is in those codes. If it is true, we print out true and return true. What `return True` does is it allows us to collect the result of the function. So if we want to use the result of the checkCourseCode function later in the code, we can do that.

```py
        else:
          print("False")
          return False
    else:
      print("False")
      return False
```

Here we are just saying that if the last one wasn't correct then we will print and return False. We need to do it on both lines as we have 2 if statements.

---

And finally, we are done! Let's try it.

```py
input_word = input("Please select menu choice: ")
checkCourseCode(input_word)
```

This should result in:

```
Please select menu choice: COMP 123
True
```

Success!

---

### I want the full code now please

```py
courses = {
  "COMP":("215", "123"),
  "LASC":("215", "1712"),
  "ENGN":("281", "192")
}

def checkCourseCode(input_word):
    input_data = input_word.split(" ")
    if len(input_data) != 2:
        return False
    if input_data[0] in courses:
        if input_data[1] in courses[input_data[0]]:
            print("True")
            return True    
        else:
            print("False")
            return False
    else:
        print("False")
        return False
input_word = input("Please select menu choice: ")
checkCourseCode(input_word)
```

Comment: I wasn't sure how to work-around the dictionary declaration after or before the def() function. thanks for the clear instruction.

Comment: btw, your ‘else:’s are redundant. You can have ‘return False’ at the end of your function and be done with it.